# How to remove the $ dollar sign in R

Tags: r, symbols

[image: overview data 1]
[image: overview data 2]

how can i remove the dollar signs? see the data i tried a lot of things already and nothing works.

i separated the columns sales_revenue to sales_revenue_A, sales_revenue_B, sales_revenue_C, sales_revenue_D. See the images.

Used the function like : as.nummeric and gsub but i get errors en this is my first time i am using R.

Comment: Please (1) post your data as text, not screenshots; (2) tell us what you've tried and what errors are occurring (as text, not screenshots)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a `dplyr` solution, where `df` is your dataframe:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Sales"), ~gsub("\\$", "", .) %>% as.numeric))
```

`mutate` creates a new column, `across(starts_with("Sales")` references the columns that start with "Sales", and the tilde `~` begins the `gsub` function, which replaces all instances of "$" with nothing (i.e., "").

And of course if you want to save as a new dataframe, you would need to call:

```
dfnew <- df %>% 
      mutate(across(starts_with("Sales"), ~gsub("\\$", "", .) %>% as.numeric))
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(Sales_revenue1 = c("$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", 
"$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", 
"$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", 
"$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", "$100", 
"$100", "$100", "$100", "$100"), Sales_revenue2 = c("$200", "$200", 
"$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", 
"$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", 
"$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", 
"$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200", "$200"), Sales_revenueB = c("$300", 
"$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", 
"$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", 
"$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", 
"$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300", "$300")), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: OP noted `as.numeric`, easy enough to tack this onto `mutate`: `~str_replace(., "\\$", "") %>% as.numeric` (or `gsub`)

Comment: or use `gsub` with the `fixed=T` in order to treat the dollar sign as a literal dollar. And explain that this is due to `gsub` accepting regex by default and that the dollar sign is a special character (in regex) that denotes end of string .....

Comment: @andrew_reece @Abdessabour Mtk both good points - I updated to add `as.numeric` since OP requested, and kept the regex escapes since it's good to know, and there wasn't a specific request from OP.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` with `gsub` in `base R`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = "$", fixed = TRUE, replacement = "")
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c("$100", "$250", "$50.5"), v2 = c("$100/$222/$23/$111", 
"$2/$200/$111", "$1000/$100/$222/$23/$111")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply` `gsub` to the whole dataframe to replace `$`, which is a regex metacharacter and therefore needs to be escaped using `\\`:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("\\$", "", x))
```

which gives, based on some mock data, this:

```
df <- data.frame(
      v1 = c("$100", "$250", "$50.5"),
      v2 = c("$100/$222/$23/$111", "$2/$200/$111", "$1000/$100/$222/$23/$111")
)
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("\\$", "", x))
df
     v1     v2                   
[1,] "100"  "100/222/23/111"     
[2,] "250"  "2/200/111"          
[3,] "50.5" "1000/100/222/23/111"
```